# ASP.NET MVC 4 can't find stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4. I am using two databases, my database and the default database for the login and registration.

Everything was excellent and I could call my stored procedures, until I tried to make my own membership. What I mean I tried to customize the websecurity. I really don't know anything about that thing, I maybe use the wrong words right now. However, I did some changes on my class as a question here said. then I run my application, it now gives me an exception and I knew it is hard to me so I make (ctrl + z) for all my classes that I change. Then I run, I got this exception

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.ApartmentOwnerLogin'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.ApartmentOwnerLogin'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 395:                new ObjectParameter("password", typeof(string));
>   Line 396:
>   Line 397:            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("ApartmentOwnerLogin", usernameParameter, passwordParameter, iD);
>   Line 398:        }

I really reversed (undo) all the changes that I did

Please help me to return to the work.

Please help me, I am almost finished all what I have to do and this day before I give my project, I got this exception

Comment: just check whether stored proc. exists in edmx model , under stored procedure...does that proc exists at sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) If you're doing your own membership you probably don't need a stored procedure to login, just return the user by username and then check their password in code.

B) To check your SP if you're going down that route, do the following:

1. Check that the SP exists within your EDMX, do this via the model browser
2. Check that the SP exists on your Database Server, via SSMS
3. Check that you can execute the SP as yourself on SSMS with appropriate params
4. Check that the user your website is connecting to the db with (likely a SQL login) can both connect to the database and has execute permissions to the stored procedure.

(4 may actually be a pre-cursor to 1!)

The order to check should really be, 2,3,4,1

Failure at 2. If it doesn't exist on the DB server...create it
Failure at 3. Ensure the procedures params and permissions are what you expect and that it's named correctly.
Failure at 4. Ensure the user from your connection string exists as a login on the DBserver, as a login on the database and has execute permissions on that SP.
Failure at 1. Go to 'update model from database' in VS, find the sp and add it in

Comment: for some reason the sp are not existed in my edmx because tthe model browser shows me empty stored procedure, however i have then in a text script, how can i add them back please?

Comment: i mean i clicked on the my mdf file and then the server exploror open, there i check the stored prcedure, but nothing found

Comment: If you can't find the SP when you're trying to add it to the edmx file then it either doesn't exist on the database or you don't have execute permissions to it...as specified in the answer

Comment: i do have all the permissions, i am the owner of my pc, and all the work on my pc, before 10 hours i was able to call them all, but when i played with this `memebership` thing, they removed although i redo all the changes. i have them in my another mdf file, actually, i made new edmx with new connection and now i call them good. but i want the old connection because the data is there. to sum up. how can i add them to the connection allready exist. sorry if i use not correct words but english is not good with me. i hope you understand me.

Comment: The best way to sync your edmx if you already have the database is to open it up, right click in some blank area and select 'Update Model From Database', this will use the connection defined for that model when it was created. This will open a window listing your database objects, expand the 'Stored Procedures and Functions' area and find your SP, click the checkbox to include it and click 'Finish' this will import the SP into your edmx.